# How to convert vector of uint8_t into std::string in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I'm trying to convert the bytes in to string correctly. But the converted string looks like a garbage. I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

 std::string HexString( std::vector<std::uint8_t> &bytes ) {
                std::stringstream ss;
                for ( std::int32_t i = 0; i < bytes.size(); i++ ) {
                    if(i != 0)
                        ss << ",";
                    ss << bytes[i];
                }
                return ss.str();
}

int main() {
    std::vector<uint8_t> uuid = {
                 0x41,0x7c, 0xea, 0x9a,0xaf
    };
    
    std::string uuidString = HexString(uuid);
    
    std::cout << "Should be equal" << std::endl;
    std::cout << uuidString << std::endl;
    std::cout << "0x41, 0x7c, 0xea, 0x9a, 0xaf" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Both should be equal:
A,|,�,�,�
0x41, 0x7c, 0xea, 0x9a, 0xaf
```

Correct output should be:

```
Both should be equal:
0x41, 0x7c, 0xea, 0x9a, 0xaf
0x41, 0x7c, 0xea, 0x9a, 0xaf
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: strings aren't for bytes, they are for characters.  You are getting the output of the characters with those hex values.  Why do you want a string of binary data?  `vector` or `array` are the normal containers to use when using binary data.

Comment: The stream "output" operator `<<` will write *all* `char`-based types (and `uint8_t` is based on `char`) as characters, not integers.

Comment: As @Someprogrammerdude mentioned, you got the corresponding characters for these numbers. 0x41 corresponds to "A", 0x7c corresponds to "|" and so one. The other "strange characters" that ypu printed are either non-printable characters, or characters in the the extended ascii table (see the values [here](https://web.itu.edu.tr/sgunduz/courses/mikroisl/ascii.html)).

Answer (score 4):

- Your `uint8_t` values are being interpreted as characters. Convert them to integers for stream operations
- Use [`std::hex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) for stream operations to convert integers to hexadecimal representation
- Add "0x", as `std::hex` won't do that for you.
- Add a space after your comma

```
std::string HexString(std::vector<std::uint8_t> &bytes)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < bytes.size(); i++)
    {
        if (i != 0)
        {
            ss << ", ";
        }
        ss << "0x" << std::hex << static_cast<int>(bytes[i]);
    }
    return ss.str();
}
```

With that, I get:

```
Should be equal
0x41, 0x7c, 0xea, 0x9a, 0xaf
0x41, 0x7c, 0xea, 0x9a, 0xaf
```

Comment: "Convert them to integers for stream operations." -- To be fair, `uint8_t` *is* an integer  type(def), and its values *should* be interpreted as such.

Comment: It's probably a typedef of `unsigned char`. Without the cast, I get `0xA, 0x|, 0x�, 0x�, 0x�` in the output instead of hex values. Yuck.

Comment: @DevSolar `uint8_t` is typically an alias for `unsigned char`, so it can be quite pesky.  This is one reason `std::byte` was added.

Comment: Usually, hex bytes are printed with 2 digits. This answer will print e.g. 5 as 0x5. To fix this is really cumbersome in C++: `ss << "0x" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << std::right << std::hex << static_cast<int>(bytes[i]);`.

Comment: @nielsen: Fair enough. But is the `std::right` really necessary if they're all going to be the same width anyway?

Comment: @FredLarson: I am aware of that. I wanted to point out that it is "sold" as 8-bit int, so someone might assume it should *behave* like one. Especially since the underlying type -- `unsigned char` -- is already meant to indicate non-character data in C. {shrug} Even C++ isn't perfect.

Comment: @FredLarson Yes, `std::right` is needed so that zeroes are inserted before the number. However, it is the default setting for standard streams, so usually it is not needed to state it explicitly.

Comment: @DevSolar: On some platforms, `char` *is* `unsigned char`. Whether `char` is signed or unsigned is implementation defined.

Comment: @nielsen: Ah, I understand. It wouldn't do to have the zeroes inserted on the wrong end.

Comment: @FredLarson If I remember it correctly, `char`, `unsigned char`, `signed char` should be 3 distinct type, despite two of them are actually the same.

Comment: The `char` type is *defined* to be a separate type from both `signed char` and `unsigned char`. It just happens to share value range and representation with one of them.